# The 'difference' in 2 numbers wont print: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str"

Tags: python, pycharm, integer, stock

I am trying to create just a simple 50% retracement Fibonacci point of the high and low of Nasdaq data I have loaded up via csv. The max and min price will print; along with the first 10 rows of data. The only exception is, i am finding it difficult to have the correct function typed up for: "difference = max_price_1 - min_price_1 and the following error prints: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

I tried computing it with the 'int' and 'str' function. Noobie here, have only been on Python for around a month. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Pizzle/Documents/NQ 100 Data.csv")

min_price = df["Price"].min()
max_price = df["Price"].max()
max_price_1 = (max_price)
min_price_1 = (min_price)

difference = max_price_1 - min_price_1 THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP

print(difference)
print(min_price_1)
print(min_price_1)
print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: You can not subtract a string from another string. Maybe try `difference = float(max_price_1) - float(min_price_1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `Price` column to numeric as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Pizzle/Documents/NQ 100 Data.csv")

# Convert the 'Price' column to a numeric data type (float)
df["Price"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Price"], errors="coerce")

min_price = df["Price"].min()
max_price = df["Price"].max()
max_price_1 = (max_price)
min_price_1 = (min_price)

difference = max_price_1 - min_price_1

print(difference)
print(min_price_1)
print(max_price_1)
print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: So i did get a return of data but where the min, max, and difference were supposed to print it output three nan values. No worries, though! thank you for the help